# sending Json from JavaScript to codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json

Output function javascript: (use json.stringify)

"[\"Lighthouse(1).jpg\",\"Penguins(2).jpg\"]"

how convert this output to json in c#.

Is there a function to convert to Json

tanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem here, the output data you have shown in the hidden field is in fact valid JSON. Square brackets are used to denote an array of data which is why it is showing here as you are converting a javascript array into JSON. Curly braces which is what you may be thinking of for JSON is used to denote objects in JSON. You can see more on JSON at the [w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp).

I have tested your JSON string that you have shown in a few JSON decoders for different languages and all convert the data to an array in the native language without any errors.